# TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia/Tarde/Noite,

Já fiz e refiz várias vezes o mesmo processo seguindo as especificações necessárias pra funcionar(nomear com o id correto, importar o id no js e colocar fora de função para ele poder ser utilizado em todos os lugares dentro do código, definir um nome, usar o nome para instanciar os objetos, aplicar o innerHTML para mandar um valor, colocar o + antes do valor para não apagar o que já estava antes, fiz até um window.alert para garantir que os valores realmente estavam sendo gerados) e mesmo assim o erro persiste.

(A intenção é jogar os valores pro log, o nome embaixo do botão é só um placeholder pra outra função)

```js
var log = document.getElementById("lognome");

function gerarNome(){
var RandomNames = {
    firstNames: [
      'Vinicius',
      'Talita',
      'Maria',
      'João',
      'José',
      'Marcos'
    ],
    middleNames: [
      'Costa',
      'Araújo',
      'Rodrigues',
      'Pereira',
      'Soares'
    ],
    lastNames: [
      'Pires',
      'Alves',
      'Álvares',
      'Moreira',
      'Ferreira'
    ],
    generate:function(quantity){
      var maxNames = this.firstNames.length * this.middleNames.length * this.lastNames.length;
      if (quantity > maxNames) {
        throw "Quantity greater than possible matches. Possible matches: "+maxNames;
      }
      var names = [];
      while ( names.length < quantity ) {
        var name = "";
        var first = Math.floor( Math.random() * this.firstNames.length );
        name+= this.firstNames[first];
        var middle = Math.floor( Math.random() * this.middleNames.length );
        name+= " "+this.middleNames[middle];
        var last = Math.floor( Math.random() * this.lastNames.length );
        name+= " "+this.lastNames[last];
        
        if (names.indexOf(name)==-1) {
          names.push(name);
        }
      }
      return names;
    }
  };
  
  try {
    var names = RandomNames.generate(10);
    for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
        window.alert(names[i]);
        log.innerHTML = + names[i];  
    //   document.write(names[i]+'<br/>');
    }
    // document.write('<br /><strong>Total names:</strong> '+names.length);
  } catch (e) {
    document.write(e);
  }
}

function limparlog(){
    log.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
.btnr{
    clear: both;
    background: rgba(26,26,64,1) ;    
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px -2px rgba(54,54,54,1);

}

.btnr:hover{
  outline: none;
    cursor:grab;
    background-color:  rgba(24,24,58,1); /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px -2px rgba(54,54,54,1);

}

.log{
  font-size: 14px;;
  cursor: default;
  scrollbar-color: #000000;
  border-color: #00000000;
  color: aliceblue;
  background-color: #00000046;
  font-size: 2em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  resize: none;
  width: 750px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 25px;
}

.btnl{
  position: relative;
  background: #141414;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px -2px rgba(54,54,54,1);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--Styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Scripts-->
    <script language="javascript" src="Scripts/script.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="Scripts/index.js"></script>
    <!--Meta-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>
        Gerador de Nomes
    </title>
</head>

<body class="bg">
    <!-- <header class="top">
        <div>
                <a class="navbtn" href="./index.html"></i><h2 class="main"></i>Site do RPG<i class="fas fa-dice-d20" id="icon"></i></h2></a>

                <a class="navbtn" href="./menu.html"><p class="main">Menu</p></a>
                
                <a class="navbtn" href="./contador.html"><p class="main">Contador</p></a>
                
                <a class="navbtn" href="./dados.html"><p class="main">Dados</p></a>
                
                <a class="navbtn" href="./fichas.html"><p class="main">Fichas</p></a>

                <div class="search">
                    <a class="fas fa-search" id="icon" href="http:\\www.google.com"></a>
                </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div> 

            <div class="sidemenudados"> 

                    <div class="sidemenucontent"> 

                        <a href="./menu.html">
                            <h2><i id="icond" class="fas fa-calculator" id="icon"></i></h2>
                        </a>

                        <a href="./contador.html">
                            <h2><i id="icond" class="fas fa-clock" id="icon"></i></h2>
                        </a>

                        <a href="./dados.html">
                            <h2><i id="icond" class="fas fa-dice-d20" id="icon" ></i></h2>
                        </a>

                        <a href="./fichas.html">
                        <h2><i id="icond" class="fas fa-address-card" id="icon"></i></h2>
                        </a>

                        <h2><i id="icond" class="fas fa-cheese" id="icon"></i></h2>

                    </div>
                </div> -->

            <div class="menudsgn"> <!--Casewrapping-->
                    <div class="center"> <!--Centering Prop.-->
                            <div class="middle"> <!--Module Top-->
                                <div class="aligname"> <!--Interior Alignment-->

                                    <h1>Gerador de Nomes</h1>
                                    <button class="btnr" onclick="gerarNome()" id="generate-name">Gerar</button>
                                    <h2>
                                    <span class='color' id='color-name'>Geralt</span>
                                    <span class='surname' id='sur-name'>de Rivia</span>
                                    </h2>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="middle2"> <!--Module Bottom-->
                                <label class="logtext">Log de Nomes</label>
                                <textarea spellcheck="false" id="lognome" class="log" readonly></textarea>
                                <button class="btnl" onClick="limparlog()" id="limparlog">Limpar Log</button> 
                            </div>
                    </div>   
            </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual linha dá esse erro? Ao executar seu código, nenhum erro é mostrado.

Comment: Nenhuma linha está sendo apontada (uso VS Code), o erro só é capturado pela var "e" e é mostrado com document.write() substituindo toda a página pelo erro ao invés da lista de nomes
ref: [link](https://i.imgur.com/247t8ns.png)

Comment: Vc está executando o script antes do HTML, assim ele não acha o elemento `#lognome`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está carregando o script no `<head>`, com isso a linha:

```
var log = document.getElementById("lognome");
```

Não achou o elemento `#lognome` que ainda não foi carregado, com isso dando erro na referência, que será `null`.

Para corrigir isso, você pode atribuir o valor à variável `log` após o DOM ser carregado, desta forma:

```
var log; // declara a variável sem nenhum valor atribuído
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   // após o DOM ter sido carregado,
   // atribui o elemento à variável
   log = document.getElementById("lognome");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa!

Ali no teu JS, nesse trecho:

```
try {
var names = RandomNames.generate(10);
for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
    window.alert(names[i]);
    log.innerHTML += names[i];  
//   document.write(names[i]+'<br/>');
}
// document.write('<br /><strong>Total names:</strong> '+names.length);
```

}

Corrige a linha

```
log.innerHTML = + names[i];
```

para

```
log.innerHTML += names[i];
```

Comment: É uma boa prática de programação diminuir o " x = x + y" pra "x += y", mas infelizmente não resolve o erro de referência

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui nesse Pencode https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJZEzm.

Foi a única alteração que fiz e deu certo. Além disso, também vc tem que carregar esse seu javascript no final do codigo HTML, pois como já respondido ai em cima, se vc carrega o JS antes da DOM, o codigo não vai conseguir achar o document.getElementById("lognome");